# Changing first item in nested list using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Let's say I have the following list of lists:

```
[['Hello im an item', 1234], ['I enjoy python', 'hello'], ['I only have one item']]
```

I want to replace the spaces with underscores in the first item in each inner list so it looks like this:

```
[['Hello_im_an_item', 1234], ['I_enjoy_python', 'hello'], ['I_only_have_one_item']]
```

I have tried the following with no success:

```
formatted = [first[0].replace(' ', '_') for first in formatted]
```

formatted returns a list of only the first items, but with the correct formatting.
Does anyone have any idea how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A list comprehension builds an entirely new list, so you need to ensure that that new list contains everything the old list contained. Concatenate the remainder of each sublist:

```
formatted = [[sub[0].replace(' ', '_')] + sub[1:] for sub in formatted]
```

As a regular `for` loop, the above is roughly equivalent to:

```
_new = []
for sub in formatted:
    _element = [sub[0].replace(' ', '_')] + sub[1:]
    _new.append(_element)
formatted = _new
```

Rather than use a list comprehension, you could just alter your list in-place with a regular loop:

```
for sub in formatted:
    sub[0] = sub[0].replace(' ', '_')
```

Only use the list comprehension if you absolutely need a completely new list.

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! I was unaware you could add the second item in the list after replacing the first item, perfect for my situation.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `for` loop:

```
for a in formatted:
    a[0] = a[0].replace(' ', '_')
```

This really isn't a use-case for list comprehensions.